# Set current worksheet as a variable in order to work with formulas easier

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set my current active worksheet as a variable in order to be able to use vlookups easier without having issues. The reason that I want to do that is because I run this macro daily and each day the active worksheet has new name (the new date). Now inside my macro I use ActiveSheet but I use a lot of vlookups and go back and forth so it crushes.. I will provide the beginning of the code so as to be more clear.. All I need is a way to set the current active book as a variable. This way, even if the active worksheet changes, the old current worksheet will be saved as a variable

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
Worksheets.Add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "_Daily_RCCP"
With ActiveSheet
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

As you can see the active worksheet changes two times.. So, I want to set the last active worksheet as a variable

Comment: `Dim ws as Worksheet`  and `Set ws = ActiveSheet`?

Comment: and if I want to do two active worksheets then when there is the first worksheets I do  Dim ws1 s as Worksheet and Set ws1 = ActiveSheet and when the other current activeworksheet is used then I do Dim ws2 as Worksheet and Set ws2 = ActiveSheet and both worksheets are saved as if they were named ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw out what @ScottCraner mentioned in comment.

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

Worksheets.Add.Name = ws1.Name & "_Daily_RCCP"

Dim ws2 as Worksheet
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet 'bc adding a sheet automatically makes it active

ws1.Cells.Copy

With ws2.Cells
    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With

'n.b. - i would personally avoid copying all the cells in a worksheet
'instead copying the usedrange or some defined range
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to slightly rewrite Scott Holtzman answer:

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
'here you add a sheet and directly assign it to a variable
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add.Name = ws1.Name & "_Daily_RCCP"

ws1.Cells.Copy

With ws2.Cells
    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
```

Also take notice that each sheet has 2 names: the tab name the user sees (`.Name`), and the other name you can only see from VBE (`.CodeName`).
Actually, if you put some code behind Sheet1 (CodeName), you can also refer to it using `Me` (current class object), exactly like you can use `ThisWorkbook` to designate the workbook containing the code.

You could therefore rewrite the above this way:

```
Dim ws2 as Worksheet
'here you add a sheet and directly assign it to a variable
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add.Name = Sheet1.Name & "_Daily_RCCP"
'No need for an extra variable ws1 since we use the CodeName

sheet1.Cells.Copy

With ws2.Cells
    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
```

or if the code is behind Sheet1:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add
ws2.Name = Me.Name & "_Daily_RCCP"
'No need for an extra variable ws1 since we use Me
Me.Cells.Copy

ws2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```